Is "avoid extra null pointer risk" a reason to avoid "introduce parameter objects"?
According to Should we avoid custom objects as parameters?, I know I can group related parameters to improve readability of the function, eg:
Original version:
public void showSchedule(long startDate,long endDate){
    //some code to display start date and end date
}

this.showSchedule(myStartDate,myEndDate);

"Introduce parameter objects" version:
public class ShowScheduleParameters{
    public long startDate;
    public long endDate;
}

public void showSchedule(ShowScheduleParameters showScheduleParameters){
    long startDate=showScheduleParameters.startDate;
    long endDate=showScheduleParameters.endDate;
    //some code to display start date and end date
}

ShowScheduleParameters showScheduleParameters=new ShowScheduleParameters();
showScheduleParameters.startDate=myStartDate;
showScheduleParameters.endDate=myEndDate;
this.showSchedule(showScheduleParameters);

which the object helps to display the name of parameters, reduce the chance of interchanging startDate and endDate like this.showSchedule(myEndDate,myStartDate); .
However, I found "Introduce parameter objects" version isn't perfect: I may pass null to showSchedule accidentally, whereas with the original version this never happens. Although I can add a check to the function:
public void showSchedule(ShowScheduleParameters showScheduleParameters){
    if(showScheduleParameters==null){
        //some code to handle
    }
    long startDate=showScheduleParameters.startDate;
    long endDate=showScheduleParameters.endDate;
    //some code to display start date and end date
}

But in practice, the original version doesn't need to handle this, therefore I don't want to worry about adding a flow to handle this as it adds to the complexity of the application. So I would rather keep the original version, is it the reason to avoid "introduce parameter objects"?
Note: I'm not talking about avoiding "introduce parameter objects" in all cases: if the function already contains nullable parameters which I need to handle the null case, eg:
public void showInfo(String name, int age){
    if(name==null){
        //some error dialog
    }
}

I don't care to add a additional null handling to this:
public void showInfo(ShowInfoParameters showInfoParameters){
    if(showInfoParameters==null){
        //some error dialog
    }
    if(showInfoParameters.name==null){
        //some error dialog
    }
}

but at the case at top (showSchedule), the function originally had no nullable parameters, what I care is, it requires me to add null handlings to a function that originally doesn't need to handle null.

The underlying assertion of this question seems to be that we should avoid reference types on the implied inevitability of causing null issues by doing so, as opposed to advocating for proper null handling when using a reference type. Is there a source for this implication, or is this an interpretation on your part?

Blindly grouping parameters does not improve readability. Come up with a better name, ShowScheduleParameters is horrible, it shows you did not read the linked Q&A with its comments properly, especially the first comment under the accepted answer.

"I may pass null to showSchedule accidentally, which the original version never happens this." If you omitted a non-nullable parameter, your code still would not have worked (otherwise this parameter would be pointless in the first place). You also don't forget to pass in null, you actively pass it in. If you don't trust yourself to not pass in a null, why would you trust yourself to pass in the correct parameter value even if null weren't an option? This question seems based on a half-baked idea that you haven't fully explored to understand what problem you're actually trying to prevent.

Basically, don’t base your code design on the assumption that your coworkers might be useless numpties.

@Flater And it is many times easier to pass two parameters in the wrong order than passing NULL instead of an object. In the second case, the error is obvious on the most superficial glance.

@gnasher729 In this case, I'd be surprised if start, end got passed in the wrong order, and and it's easy to check inside the function.

This depends very much upon the language.  Neither this question nor the linked question specify a language, but I guess they may be about Java, in which case it's probably a valid concern.  However, it's NOT a concern in a language with non-nullable types, such as Kotlin — there, the compiler will prevent null being passed to a param of a non-nullable type, whether directly or indirectly.  (In such cases, not only is a null check completely unnecessary, but the compiler will flag it up as such!)

@prosfilaes I once used a C++ library that had a constructor for point objects with values x, y. Then some genius changed it to v(ertically) And h(orizontally). Every single call to the constructor was wrong with no chance for the compiler to tell you.

Why are you passing longs instead of Dates in the first place? Thats already fraught with problems. And when using dates -- well, you need to take care of null anyways.

ShowScheduleParameters is a terrible name. What about DateRange?

@Polygnome One problem at a time.

If we're talking unrelated problems, "some error dialog" is not an appropriate error handling strategy in a random non-UI function on a null pointer condition.

Your observation that introducing such a parameter object may require extra thoughts about nulls is correct. Your conclusion not to introduce such a parameter object because of it isn't.
Instead, I would check which null handling options your language provides:

in Java, one could make use of the @NonNull annotation, which is AFAIK not a language feature, but supported by IDEs and other tools

in modern C#, reference types are not-nullable by default, nullable references require an extra ? at the end.

in C++, references,opposed to pointers, are never nullable.


But even in Java without annotations or older C#, I would typically not sacrifice meaningful object structure and abstractions for the price of having to write a few extra tests and some exception handler, things I often need anyways.

It is in my opinion also not necessary to check for null, in many instances. If you didn't check for unexpected int values before (which would indicate an uninitialized or default-initialized value -- if that distinction can be made at all! --, essentially the same error): Then you don't need to check the pointer either. It makes complete sense to check values -- not only pointers! -- for sanity at the borders of your responsibility, but not everywhere within. It would usually indicate a programming error; what do you do then? Throw? You do that already with a null pointer access.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: yes, I thought to add some words about the OP's misconception where the extra effort for null handling has to take place; it is typically not inside the function, but maybe on the callers side,.I currently lack some time to extend my answer properly.

What you're being tempted by has a name:
Primitive Obsession
Yes it is very nice that unboxed int's can't be null. Testing for null is a pain. But so is testing for -1. For that matter, so is testing for the carry flag. Sorry but primitives aren't perfect representations either. They also require validation*. And since we're going to be doing validation anyway we might as well treat ourselves to the best model of our domain that we can.
That said, I dream of the day I can code in a language that will let me move such validation checks into the type system where they can become compiler errors. Until then I work with what we have.
* or strict parsing, or hell any method that lets me be confident this thing is usable once it exists.

Parse, don’t validate

I would add that one can create strong types that encapsulate the primitive, give more type safety and allow for standalone validation. But now you may have more than one nullability check ...

@n0099 that was a very good read. Makes me wish more people in my shop could read Haskell.

There are languages that let you specify subtypes with more specific restrictions, such as "integer between 1 and 15".  They're often quite messy to actually use in practice, though, especially once you start doing calculations with them.  There are also libraries that provide (usually runtime rather than compile-time) stronger guarantees than primitives, such as Boost.SafeNumerics in C++.

C#'s ? and ?? have remedied 90% of my problems with null.

@jeancallisti C.O. narrows his eyes at you. You notice he's wearing a hat with an abstract coffee cup rendered in pastel blue and red. You almost see tears well up in his eyes as he says, "Oh shut up".

Null pointers are the ultimate “fail fast”. Calling your function with a null pointer would be a severe bug in the callers code. So just access the data through this pointer, there is an instant crash, and the caller fixes it.
This cannot survive testing.
Or use a language that allows nullable vs non-null pointers. In C++ pass a reference instead of a pointer.

The risk of null pointer exceptions has nothing to do with introducing parameter objects, but to do with using any nullable types for any purpose (which in a lot of OO languages is every single object type, and for some it's literally every single value you can manipulate at all).
A conclusion that you therefore ought to avoid introducing parameter objects purely because they could introduce the risk of null pointer exceptions is pretty suspicious, because if it's just about the null pointer risk it ought to apply equally to a huge portion of all the possible code you can write. That would lead to the conclusion that you essentially shouldn't write code, which doesn't sound like a very helpful guideline. (Note: I'm not saying that in any particular context there might not be other reasons to avoid parameter objects, just that this specific line of reasoning is silly)
Essentially the "right" way to address this risk is at the language level, by having a type system that can express whether parameters are allowed to be null or not (and preferably defaults to no), so that accidentally passing null is detected as a compile time error, and whether something is allowed to be null is a type property that will be visible when callers check interfaces (and guaranteed to be correctly synced as the code changes). But you're unlikely to change the language you're working in just so you can introduce a non-null parameter object to a function.
Otherwise you simply address this the same way you do any other parameter that has requirements on callers that go beyond what the compiler will enforce (like an integer that must be non-zero, say); just document the requirement. Your language, IDE, docs renderer, and/or codebase conventions may or may not have some standard way of doing this already, hopefully in a way that will easily display the information to people working on callers. "This function is never called with a null parameter object" is essentially just an invariant that your callers need to know about and maintain, every bit as much as something like "the endDate must be after the startDate"). And then you test your codebase thoroughly enough that any code paths that could break the invariant are likely to be found and fixed before they make it into production.
In the case of many other broken-invariant errors you would also put checks into the function itself that make sure the invariant holds, as you suggested. In the specific case of non-nullable invariants I actually recommend not doing that. There are simply too many objects that the language considers nullable which are in practice required to be always non-null (most of them are not parameter objects, hence why I say this ought to be manages as a very general issue, having nothing to do with when you should or shouldn't use parameter objects). And in a huge portion of cases the only reasonable thing to do if a non-nullable object turns out to be null is to throw an exception, which is exactly what will happen if you don't check and simply access the object. So just let the null pointer exception be thrown; it'll have a stack trace saying exactly where the non-nullable null was encountered (and who passed it in, though it may have originated further away of course). Your testing process should aim to ensure that this never happens in released versions, so if it does happen you want the error to fail noisily so that your tests catch it. And many code analysis tools (like IDEs) have smarter logic to detect possible null pointer errors even for languages that don't formally encode nullability into the type system, but this is much less likely to work when you explicitly check for null and throw exceptions yourself (let alone other effects like logging or displaying messages), since the presence of such code implies that this might be expected runtime behaviour for your function, rather than something that should be statically detected at compile time if possible. This also means that seeing if (parameter == null) { ... } inside a function becomes a good signal that passing null probably is a deliberately handled use case rather than breaking an invariant (the docs should still clearly specify what happens if the parameter is null, which is usually much more work than just requiring everything to be non-null and testing for null pointer exceptions; the expectation really ought to be that everything is non-null until you encounter a specific need to allow it).
You might want to catch these "should never happen" exceptions and do something like log the error for reporting or display a nicer message to your users, just in case they ever do actually make it to production. But the right place to do that sort of thing is usually in a fairly outer layer of your program where you catch null pointers from anywhere. You don't want to repeat that logic every possible place that a null pointer exception could originate, because there's just too much of it (and many of those places won't be in code that really has any business knowing about things like UI functions for displaying an error dialog, and you definitely shouldn't add such a dependency just for this purpose).

I think there's a small benefit to doing a null check on parameters on entry; the exception is then targeted and you can see that the problem is the parameter that was passed in, not some other bug inside the routine.

@Craig When a null pointer exception comes from the first use of a parameter, can't you tell that the problem was the parameter that was passed in? Yes, you can probably make it very slightly more informative, but I've never seen it done in a way that felt worth the huge amount of boilerplate you have to skim over every time you read the function if you really check every parameter for null, even if your IDE can autogenerate the checks.

If I'm debugging, then it's obvious, but I can't tell from a stack trace that it's the first use---I'm not even sure I can tell in that context whether it's the parameter (I don't remember now whether the stack trace includes which variable was null).  An ArgumentNullException is also effectively API documentation for anything that might be used in a package without access to the source.

If you're concerned about confusing myStartDate and myEndDate, use named parameter notation; e.g. in Python or Scala "showSchedule (myStartDate = 0, myEndDate = 100)". This is not supported in all object orientated languages, but Ada, C#, Kotlin, Python, Scala and Swift all support it.

I'll make a comment an answer because I think it is a general guideline.
It is not always necessary to check for null pointers in code you call yourself. It typically indicates a programming error. The program is in an invalid state. How do you recover from there? Throw? Duh.
It does make a whole lot of sense to check and, if appropriate, reject data from others that is not under your control (e.g. input, calls into your api). Often, such checks are essential simply for secure programming. Did you do that with the dates before? No? Then you don't need to do that now. A null pointer is not different from any other invalid data. In fact, you are now much better off than before: Now errors will be diagnosed! A date of January 1, 1970 would have gone unnoticed and would have caused hard-to-find problems. But now, a null pointer crashes your program with a stack trace (since you seem to work with a language like C# or Java).
There may be situations where defensive programming even within your own code is warranted because a crash would do too much damage, but then you really should have had a value check at that point before already.

In cases where it's necessary to expose a data-holding object to code that would be statically capable of accessing arbitrary portions thereof before it would be possible for all of its fields to hold meaningful content, having uninitialized content hold null wasn't a "billion dollar mistake", but was better than any alternative approach, especially in situations where one might need to copy a partially-written object.  What would be helpful would be if frameworks could include metadata that would allow a null-pointer trap to report the type of pointer and the name of the accessed field.

@supercat In the OP's programming environment that information is probably readily available.

Any programming environments I've used recently would at best narrow the location to a single source line, which may perform multiple dereferences, e.g. even if one knows a trap occurs while processing myCar.goto(mySettings.defaultDestination.location, mySettings.toolPreferences.detault);, it may be unclear which part of the expression is unexpectedly null.

@supercat That's true. I was thinking of debugging, and then in C++ it'd be equally clear.

@supercat. You don’t win prices for fitting everything into one line. Location = xxx; preferred tool = yyy; mycar.goto(location, preferred tool).

@gnasher729: If a method requires multiple arguments, most coding conventions would write them on one line if they fit.  If nothing else near the call site needs mySettings.defaultDestination nor mySettings.toolPreferences, defining new temporary objects to hold those references would add visual clutter without really adding anything useful semantically.

It gives the ability to the debugger to show you which parameter failed. That isnt “nothing useful”.
